# Controller in External file inside angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem. I have a controller:

```
app.controller("controllerLots", ["$scope", "factoryClient", "factoryLots", "factoryContracts", "fillTicketFactory", function ($scope, factoryClient, factoryLots, factoryContracts, fillTicketFactory) {
    var vm1 = this;
    vm1.lot = {};
    vm1.lots = [];
    vm1.client = {};
    vm1.ticket = {};
    vm1.clientFindDB = [];
    // vm1.filterName =vm1.client.clientName +""+vm1.client.clientFn+"" +vm1.client.clientPatroncyr;
    // vm1.filterPassport = vm1.client.clientSerialPass + vm1.client.clientNumberPass;



    vm1.selectClient =function(client){
        vm1.client=client;
        vm1.filterName = vm1.client.clientName +''+vm1.client.clientFn +''+vm1.client.clientPatroncyr;
        vm1.filterPassport = vm1.client.clientSerialPass +""+vm1.client.clientNumberPass;
    }

    vm1.addLot = function () {
        if (angular.isUndefined(vm1.lot.orderNumberLot) || vm1.lot.n <= 0) {
            vm1.lots.push(vm1.lot);
            vm1.lot.n = vm1.lots.length;
        }
        vm1.lot = {};
    }
```

and I have a directive in which I want to put some functions from above controller, this is my directive now looks like:

```
app.directive("searchDir", [function(){
    return{
        scope:{
            filterName: '=',
            filterPass:'='
        },
        templateUrl:'searchDirective.html',
        replace:true,
        controllerAs:'ctrl',
        controller:controller
    }  }]);
```

How can I use those functions inside my directive? thanks.

Comment: You can research on how to use directive scope function binding `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use those functions inside my directive?

I guess what you are asking is how you can use those functions in your directive template. For that you need to add all the properties, that you want to access in the template, to the "scope".

1. In your directive change the controller property of the directive like:

   controller: 'controllerLots'
2. And in your controller, instead of adding properties to **"this"**, add the properties to **"$scope"**.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried what you suggested, however nothing happened.

Comment: Hi. So where are you exactly trying to use those methods. If you can share your js and html files would help in knowing what exactly is going on.